# import com.google.cloud.backend.R; missing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am working through the android sample set up but am missing the R.java

I have downloaded the sample android project from here:  https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/

When I unzip it there is no R.java in the directory com.google.cloud.backend.

I just have two files: GCMBroadcastReceiver.java and GCMIntentService.java

I am using Eclipse. My understanding is that R.java is autogenerated for each project. I was thinking that as this is a self contained sample project that the R.java file would be present.

What am I missing? Can I get eclipse to generate this file for me?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have found that if I change the projct build target to "Google APIs 4.4" instead of "Google APIs 4.0.3" then the errors disappear. This seems weird though because the file R.java still does not exist?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the R.java!

It is in gen/com/google/cloud/backend/

It does not seem to be in the source. Not sure how it got compiled though but I'll investigate that a bit more.

EDIT

I managed to get it to compile the R.java by changing the API Build Target to Google APIs 19. This seemed to force it to create the R.java. I then seemed able to revert the build target to APIs 15

EDIT2
Not sure if changing the API worked by itself. When I added theproject id to the consts.java then it seemed to compile and create an R.java file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue i.e."import com.google.cloud.backend.R" was failing.

There was no R.java getting generated under gen/com/google/cloud/backend/

Installing the build tools for API 19 and restarting Eclipse fixed the issue. i.e. R.java got generated and import started working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install "Google Play Services" in SDK Manager. After that go to eclipse and import the existing Android Application project located in `<SDK-Folder>\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject`.
Next, go to your eclipse project `CloudBackendAndroidClient`, right click --> `properties`. Go to `Android` and add the project you previously imported as a library.